# ldd -d libphp5.so resulting multiple undefined symbol errors. How to fix the same?

Tags: apache2.4, php-5.6, undefined-symbol

Installed Apache 2.4.54 and PHP 5.6.32 from the source.

Here are the *configure* options used.

Apache:

```
./configure \
        --prefix=${APACHE_PREFIX} \
        --enable-module=most \
        --enable-rewrite \
        --enable-auth-digest \
        --enable-ssl \
        --with-openssl-dir=${OPENSSL} \
        --with-included-apr \
        --enable-lib64 \
        --with-httpd24 \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --enable-so \
        --with-mpm=worker \
        --enable-cgi
```

And PHP:

```
./configure \
        --prefix=${PHP_PREFIX} \
        --with-config-file-path=${PHP_PREFIX}/lib \
        --with-tsrm-pthreads \
        --disable-short-tags \
        --enable-mbstring \
        --enable-opcache \
        --with-xsl=${LIBXSLT_PREFIX} \
        --with-zlib=${ZLIB_PREFIX} \
        --with-openssl-dir=${OPENSSL} \
        --with-ssl \
        --with-gd
```

The installation is successful.

There is shared object file *libphp5.so* got created under apache2_installation/modules directory.

When `apachectl -M` is executed, it says *php5_module* is loaded.

When `apachectl -t` is executed, it says *Syntax OK`*.

However, when `ldd -d libphp5.so` is executed, it says:

```
undefined symbol: ap_server_root    (./libphp5.so)
undefined symbol: apr_pool_cleanup_null (./libphp5.so)
undefined symbol: ap_unixd_config   (./libphp5.so)
undefined symbol: ap_loaded_modules (./libphp5.so)
```

Thought, I might have missed something. Then tried docker image `php:5.6-apache`. And still result is same.

When libphp5.so is used as dependency in other sources, I am running into above issue. And unable to proceed.

Just looking for way to overcome the above undefined symbol issues, searched a lot with futile.

Appreciate any help!

EDIT:

Found this [link](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=16598) which says to use Apache 2.2 but I had to use with TLS v1.3.

Comment: _"Appreciate any help!"_ - great. Have you tried upgrading this stack that's out of support for five years already?

Comment: I understand and had to use php 5.6. By the way, tried `php:7.4-apache` docker image to just see though and still the same issue.

Comment: Yes I understand you have reasons, but do you understand that that PHP version is out of support for five years already and that you can mitigate that by upgrading the application?

Comment: @CodeCaster, Got your point. As mentioned in previous comment, that's why tried  php7 docker to quickly see if that goes away which is not the case.